# why do I have problems connecting remotely to oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to oracle database on the following ip 192.168.1.1 port 1521
The firewall is off
but I'm still unable to connect i get the following error while using oracle sql developer: "the network adapter could not establish the connection"
The port 1521 is opened since i could connect to it on localhost
any help?

Comment: This can be due to multiple reasons. Can you connect locally on the server? Can you tnsping the port?

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen That site doesn't have a good reputation in Oracle community. Not everything that comes up on Google search is good, it is just a game of search engine indexing.

Comment: Is the Oracle DB listener running?

Comment: @LalitKumarB Well it certainly depends what is on the site. If it can help you I would say its usable. But i have removed the link to not offend someone.

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen No objection to you at all mate. I know you want to help, but believe me, I am telling it out of my experience on this site and other Oracle forums. And thanks for taking a quick action :-)

Comment: what does lsrnctl status say? if it's not started then issue lsnrctl start

Comment: As you can tell in the comments there are literally a hundred reasons that could cause this. Even if the firewall is off are you sure you are forwarding port 1521 out? Are you sure the listener is running? Can you connect locally?

Answer (score 1):

> The port 1521 is opened since i could connect to it on localhost

Unless you've configured your listener with multiple addresses, it will only be listening on one, and since you can connect with localhost then it's (only) using that one. You can verify that with `lsnrctl status` which will show either localhost or 127.0.0.1, but not the external IP address 192.168.1.1.

You need to reconfigure your listener to use 192.168.1.1 instead of, or as well as, localhost before you'll be able to connect to it from anywhere else.